# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE on StreamedResponse symfony3

Tags: php, csv, symfony

I'm trying to generate a CSV file based on info pulled via an API. Before adding the StreamedResponse, I simply see the CSV output echo'd. Once I add the StreamedResponse, I receive an ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

I'm using Symfony3, but I'm relatively new to it. I have no clue why the StreamedResponse is causing the err_invalid_response.

```
$callback = function() {
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

    fputcsv($handle, $fieldNames,',');

    $data = $elq->get($query); //query is created before the callback function, as it's reused.

    foreach ($data->elements as $record) {
        $recordData = [];
        /* Parsing data from API into $recordData */
        fputcsv($handle,$recordData,",");
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
return new StreamedResponse($callback, 200, array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.date("Ymd_His").'_'.ucfirst($settings->getType()).'_export.csv"'
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a simple variable scope problem. Inside your callback function, there are unknown variables ($fieldNames, $elq, $query).

I think that you can do something like that :

```
$callback = function() use($fieldNames, $elq, $query) {
    // your code
};
```

Comment: Feel a bit stupid for missing that :) Thanks though!

Comment: Heh yep, variable scope was causing this for me too. Looks like in streamed responses you can't get the usual splendid Symfony error view, but your response is still logged if you look through the Symfony profiler for it. (Exception too.)